# How to save a user's integer input, and return a string value?

Tags: c++

Testing Environment: MS Visual 2010 Ultimate.

I have two functions that need to pass from one to the other.

function 1:

```
//Record which account was chosen
string Account::getAccountType()
{
  if (accountType == 1)
  {
    return "Account Type:  Chequing";
  }
  else
  {
    return "Account Type: Savings";
  }

};
```

This function will take the user's input and identify whether Chequing was selected or Savings.

Function 2:

```
    //Print the Account Statement 
    void Account::PrintStatement()
    {

            cout << "First Name:    " << firstName    << endl;
            cout << "Last Name:     " << lastName     << endl;
            cout << "SIN Number:    " << sinNumber    << endl;
            cout << "Account Type:  " << accountType  << endl;
            cout << "Transactions:  " << transactions << endl;
            cout << "Final Balance: " << balance      << endl;

    };
```

This function gets all the global variables that had their values returned, or inputs saved, and prints all the inputs and calculations made.

main.cpp:

```
//Retrieve client information
    cout << "Please fill out the information below for registration:" << endl;
    cout << "Enter first name:      ";
    cin.getline(firstName, 255);
    cout << "Enter last  name:      ";
    cin.getline(lastName, 255);
    cout << "Enter SIN number:      ";
    cin.getline(sinNumber, 255);
    cout << "Enter initial balance: ";
    cin >> balance;
    cout << "Enter account type:\n       Chequing - 1\n        Savings - 2 (Or any number)\n            Choice:    ";
    cin >> accountType;
    cout << "\nPlease wait..." << endl;
```

*My problem:*
When `accountType` is printed (via `PrintStatement()`), it shows the integer value that the user inputted. I understand why it does that. I just don't know how to change it so that when either 1 or a different number was used, the `PrintStatement()` function would display the appropriate account (Chequing or Savings).

*What I tried:*
I tried changing function 1 into an integer based function and have accountType equal the option of Chequing or Savings, but integers cannot store a string value. I tried using char instead but I get the const char error.

*What I'd like to do:*
I want to be able to take the user's input of any number, and pass it to the `PrintStatement()` (via another function) so it can display the appropriate account.

***EDIT*** (adding additional code for clarity)

account.cpp

```
//Initializing account entities
Account::Account(char fn[], char ln[], char sin[], double bal, int actype, int trans)
{
    strcpy(firstName, fn);
    strcpy(lastName, ln);
    strcpy(sinNumber, sin);
    balance = bal;
    accountType = actype;
    transactions = 0;
};
```

account.h

```
#define ACCOUNT_H
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class Account {

public:
    //Object constructor
     Account(char firstName[], char lastName[], char sinNumber[], double balance, int accountType, int transactions);

    //Object operations
    double DepositAmt(double amount);
    double WithdrawAmt(double amount);
    void   PrintStatement();
    double getFinalBalance(double fbal);
    string getAccountType();
    double getTransactions (double cDeposit, double cWithdraw);

private:
    //Object properties
    char firstName[255];
    char lastName[255];
    char sinNumber[255];
    double balance;
    int accountType;
    int transactions;
};
```

Comment: How about writing a function that returns the right string based on the account type, and printing that?

Comment: `cout << "Account Type:  " << getAccountType()  << endl;` ?

Comment: Don't use global variables.

Comment: @NeilKirk Hopefully this is all in a class.

Comment: @JonathanMee it is indeed all in a class, sorry for not clarifying that.

Comment: @NeilKirk why do you say not to use global variables?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad

Comment: @NeilKirk wow i never saw it like that, thank you. That makes so much sense. Ill make my adjustments immediately before i expand the program.

Comment: You're welcome. For example, if `firstName` is a global variable, how could you handle multiple people's accounts..

Comment: @Umeed +1 to offset all the downvotes. This seems like a well thought out question. I think the downvotes may just be due to the unclarity of whether your variables are member variables. I've included Microsoft's style guide in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28789497/2642059) which may be helpful to you in that regard. Hang in there: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266370/consideration-for-removing-the-downvote-button-from-questions/266670#266670

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PrintStatement() function change the output for the accountType from

```
cout << "Account Type:  " << accountType  << endl;
```

to

```
cout << getAccountType() << endl;
```

Comment: I have tried that, sorry for not mentioning it. But when i do that, it gives me " `no operator << matches these operands` "

Comment: Can you show the part where you declare your variables and the section with the imports ?

Comment: `getAccountType()` returns a `string` (which is presumably a `std::string` and not some other `string` type). There is an `<<` operator that writes a `std::string` to `std::cout`.

Comment: Done! added the declaration for the functions file, account.cpp
and added the full script of the header file, account.h

Comment: Do you include the required headers such as `<string>`?

Comment: Yes, `account.h` needs a `#include <string>` statement.

Comment: @NeilKirk  !!! oh man I can't believe i forgot to add `<string>` to the account.cpp and account.h.....ah wow i feel so dumb right now lol. Thank you so much guys! its working! Do I just save this as the answer, or one of you can post it as an answer and I select that

Comment: @Umeed your initial question was not regarding the no operator << matches these operands " so I think you can mark this as the correct answer but I'm fairly new to stackoverflow so I don't know what is best practice here.

Comment: @Waldhuette well the answer you provided was ultimately the answer I needed so I chose this anyway. thanks a lot Waldhuette!

Answer (score 1):

Your `getAccountType()` is merely a ternary statement.

If this is a `public` accessor to `accout::accountType` you should retain it and just use it in your line in question: `cout << "Account Type:  " << getAccountType() << endl`

If however `getAccountType()` is only used internally you should just replace it with a ternary statement: `(accountType == 1 ? "Account Type:  Chequing" : "Account Type: Savings")`

So your line in question would become:

```
cout << "Account Type:  " << (accountType == 1 ? "Account Type:  Chequing" : "Account Type: Savings") << endl;
```

Note, as [Neil Kirk mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28789301/how-to-save-a-users-integer-input-and-return-a-string-value#comment45854137_28789301), it's not good if these member variables are global. I believing the best of you when I say: "I'm sure they're members of `class account`." That said you should probably denote them as members somehow. [Microsoft for instance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378932%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) uses an "m_" + type prefix, so your member variable would be named: `m_iAccountType`

Comment: thats excellent advice Jonathan, thank you. I will keep all of this in mind for expanding this project. I feel so much more motivated now that I'm understanding things more. thanks so much